# swift2 how can an object of SKScene class takes a size as a parameter?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, skspritenode

i am following a tutorial

this is my code

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }
    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    }

}
```

as you see there is **no** init method. though when i do this in my view controller:

```
//Create and configure the scene
    scene = GameScene(size : skView.bounds.size)
```

where scene is:

```
 var scene: GameScene!
```

it works. how can the GameScene approves to have a init with size though i didn't code that?

any additial information about SKSprite is appreciated. i am new to this framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GameScene` is a subclass of `SKScene`, so you inherit the init with size initializer from `SKScene`.

If you <kbd>command</kbd>-click on `SKScene` in your code, it will bring up the header information for the class:

```
public class SKScene : SKEffectNode {

    /**
     Called once when the scene is created, do your one-time setup here.

     A scene is infinitely large, but it has a viewport that is the frame through which you present the content of the scene.
     The passed in size defines the size of this viewport that you use to present the scene.
     To display different portions of your scene, move the contents relative to the viewport. One way to do that is to create a SKNode to function as a viewport transformation. That node should have all visible conents parented under it.

     @param size a size in points that signifies the viewport into the scene that defines your framing of the scene.
     */
    public init(size: CGSize)
```

---

Another helpful technique in Xcode is <kbd>Option</kbd>-clicking on function calls to find out where they are defined.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work for initializers unless you explicitly call them in the code.  So a workaround is to change:

```
var scene = GameScene(size : skView.bounds.size)
```

to

```
var scene = GameScene.init(size : skView.bounds.size)
```

and then <kbd>Option</kbd>-click on `init` which brings up the following:

---

[image: SKScene initializer]

You can then click on **SKScene Class Reference** for more information.